# C & Linux: Waiting for when a file has been written to

Tags: c, linux, io, posix, termios

I'm currently working on a project that will read data from a micro-controller via serial communications.

As of right now, the program (on my computer), opens a `/dev/tty*` file and is able to read/write to it.  The micro-controller will send a packet of `n` bytes at any time.  I want to know if there is any way I can tell when all of the bytes have been written to the file?

I've been looking at the `select()` and `poll()` functions, but they seem to be only able to tell *when* a byte is ready, but not when every byte has been written.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your `n` is hardcoded you can just do (with pseudocode):

```
received_data = offset_from_last_round
while( received_data < n )
{
    use select() for waiting data to arrive
    read() all data you can, dont forget to check buffer oveflow here
    received_data += how much data was red
}
full_message = buffer[ 0 ... N - 1 ]
offset_to_next_round = buffer[ N .. received_data ]
```

If `n` is not hardcoded you need to do something like what @Golgauth suggested, or add some "end of transmission" sequence/byte to your message (which is tricky if you have binary file/data to transmit). In short: You need some sort of protocol.

Comment: The 'n' is not fixed.  I was thinking about crafting some sort of protocol, but I'm still doing some more research to see what tools linux already gives me.

Comment: @Benjamin Your question is interesting, and this would be great if you could answer your own question on this same page once you have something or chosen an option ;)

Comment: @Golggauth I'm working on a personal project right now that involves certain stuff like this.  I already have a sort of solution thought of, but it isn't really elegant, and I want to do some more research to see if there are any other tools that are available to me before I go forward with this.  Thanks for the interest though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the idea is that your binary file should start by some bytes which actually give the size that has to be read next.

- Read N bytes => gives the DATASIZE, i.e. how many bytes remaining: (FILESIZE - N)
- Read (DATASIZE) bytes => gives the data themselves (readable by blocks/packets of size n)

This is the kind of discussion we were having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139257/1715716) actually (this about how to interpret a `raw PCM wav` sound file, but this is the same point: getting the number `N` of samples, to determine how many blocks are to be read next to get the file with concern to the integrity).